# Strange Python behaviour with regex module

Tags: python, regex

I have been playing around with the [improved regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) for Python by Matthew Barnett and found a strange error (behaviour? bug?).
Consider the following code:

```
import regex as re
string = "liberty 123, equality 123, fraternity 123"
rx = r'\d+(?=,|$)'
results = re.findall(rx, string)
print (results)
```

When invoked from the command line on my Mac (`python regex.py`), I get the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'findall'`, while when I copy and paste the exact same code to the python shell, it correctly outputs

```
['123', '123', '123']
```

Can somebody enlight me please? Is this some obvious thing I am missing here?

Comment: Is `regex.py` your file?  Did you name it the exact same name as the python package you're trying to import?  I'm guessing that it's actually importing itself, which doesn't contain `findall()`

Comment: @BrendanAbel: Yes, is this a problem?

Comment: You file name is confusing the interpreter, as that name is clashing with the module `regex` that you are importing. Change the filename, and you should be good.

Comment: @BrendanAbel: You were the first, this solved it. Put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not name your modules identically to the system modules. Rename your file `regex.py` to something else, like `my_regex.py`, then delete the file `regex.pyc`, if it exists.

Comment: Damn it, that was it :-) Thanks a lot.